# Spring JDBC with Spring Boot NullPointerException on NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, gradle, spring-jdbc

I have written a program using Spring Boot with Spring JDBC.  For some reason, I am getting a `NullPointerException` on my `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`.

DAOImpl:

```java
@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    private static final TABLE_NAME = "users";

    @Autowired
    private void setjdbcTemplate(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public User getUser(String userName) {

        String userQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE user_name LIKE :username";
        MapSqlParameterSource parameterSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        parameterSource.addValue("username", userName);

        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(userQuery, parameterSource, new userRowMapper());
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```xml
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testing_schema
spring.datasource.username=****
spring.datasource.password=****
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

As far as I can tell from the [Spring documentation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbc-jdbctemplate#1-maven-dependency), this should be enough.  Additionally, the Answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36796368/getting-a-java-lang-nullpointerexception-with-spring-boot-jdbctemplate) explains that everything should be created for me and I just have to autowire.  However, I can't figure out why this is still returning null.  I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  In my calling function, I created an instance of the dao instead of autowiring it.

So, I just had to change

`UserDaoImpl userDao = new UserDaoImp();`

to

```java
@Autowired
UserDaoImpl userDao;
```